# android hashkey generated for facebook not readable

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing a facebook oauth app on android on linux and when i run
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore 
| openssl sha1 -binary
| openssl base64
for the hash key i get an unreadable text. I tried piping it to a text file, still its unreadable.
Please help

Comment: what's your OS ? i had no problems in generating hash key. I may help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unreadable text! do you mean Ascii characters right? you will have the openssl incorrect path or it doesn't exist.
I think in linux Openssl is preinstalled, in Windows i had to install Openssl cause i get that "unreadable text"

Comment: yeah!! i was copy pasting the command and the open ssl thingy wasnt running. I ran with the openssl command and it worked. Thanks